# What's a good way to debug Windows message content and destination?

Tags: windows, logging, windows-messages

I'm working on an application that simulates a Windows mouse based on other behavior.  One example is that pressing the + or - keys on the keyboard sends the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message to a target window with an appropriate delta.  The problem is that in some situations I'm having a hard time replicating the messages that *i think* windows is sending to the target application.  Are there any ways to record windows messages sent to a specific window (hopefully with a filter for which messages I want to catch) and then review that data later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio, that comes with Spy++, which does exactly this job.

An alternative is [Winspector - Ultimate Windows Message Spy](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Winspector-Download-117157.html)