# Automating IE8 download window using WinApi

Tags: java, winapi, internet-explorer-8, jna

My current task is the automated testing of an enterprise web-based software suite using Selenium on Java.

I've more or less successfully done the trick using JNA and WinApi, unfortunately, I've hit a nasty snag.

While changing the path to the download location via the `WM_SETTEXT` message, only the visual content of the file path changes, and after clicking the save button it still saves to the originally suggested location. What gives?

Is there any way I can make IE8 think I actually entered the path manually, or, perhaps send some other message that would trigger processing of the changed address?

---

A little background:

Unfortunately, Selenium cannot handle file downloads, and I need to verify the validity of the to-be-downloaded file so a simple HTTP 200 code check will not suffice.

Automatic file downloading is out, as I'm stuck with IE8, which does not support it. Direct HTTP requests are also out - SSO authentication and HTTPS have caused too many problems down this research vector.

P.S.: Unfortunately, I cannot provide a direct code snippet due to NDA, proprietary limits and other dull limitations...

Comment: Monitor the message queue and see if there are additional messages generated when you manually set the text.

Comment: @technomage, could you elaborate a bit on the message queue please? Will IE even let me read it from outside of it's own execution area? I assume you mean messages getting received by the dialogue window, not the edit control? Sorry, I know next to nothing about messages, I need a bit more to go on.

Comment: See the response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456010/whats-a-good-way-to-debug-windows-message-content-and-destination).

Comment: Did you consider using automation for your, er, automation task.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @technomage, interesting, I didn't notice message capture functionality in WinSpy... I'll do a bit more digging around. Cheers!

Comment: Windows has an automation framework. Do you know about it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, apparently not. I'll take a look at it then, might offer some advantages over winapi...